# How do I center two floating elements next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div blocks with images inside them and I have them correctly aligned with each other, but i have them aligned to the left. I tried aligning them to the center but then they end up on top of each other.  Should I create a block around them and center that maybe?

[image: page]

```css
body {
  background-color: #C8C8C8;
  background-image: images/rottenlargebg.png;
}
h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 3px gray;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
img.width {
  width: 100%;
}
img.tLeft {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3em;
}
img.tRight {
  float: right;
}
.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(images/rottenlargebg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  float: left;
}
.div2 {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.div3 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  float: left;
}
strong {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="movie.css">

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img class="width" src="images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2015)</h1>

  <!---block one--->
  <div class="div1">
    <img class="tLeft" src="images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" /> <strong>33%</strong>
  </div>

  <!--block two-->
  <div class="div2">
    <img class="tRight" src="images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: yes thats exactly what you have to do XD

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please boil your code down to a (minimal, complete, verifiable example)[stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] - that'll help us target your question directly - the faster we can assess your problem, the better the chance you'll get answers :) (fwiw, in this case my first question would be why `float`?)

Comment: yes to `Should i create a block around them and center that maybe`

Comment: That's all the code i currently have, i just wanted to fix the problem before i add more things.  But sorry about answering my own question, i guess I just needed to bounce some ideas off.  And floats because that is what we are currently learning.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flexboxes](https://bocoup.com/weblog/dive-into-flexbox) to center two elements next to each other.
place the two divs inside a container. add the property `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to the container

for example:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/binarytrance/oy2yznsz/1/)

Side note: add `flex:1` to each div inside to maintain equal height.

Answer (score 1):

Change `float` to `display: inline-block` and set `text-align: center` to outer container.